# Cleveref produces incorrect labels when I cross-reference theorem-like environments

Tags: cleveref, amsthm

If I set the counter of corollaries to follow `theorem`, `cleveref` incorrectly uses the label *theorem* in the text, rather than *corollary*. How can I correct this?

Minimum working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
% \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}    % This works

\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}  \label{thm1}
    Theorem level result.
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}  \label{cor1}
    Corollary of \cref{thm1}.
\end{corollary}

Reference to \cref{cor1}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load the `cleveref` package right before issuing the `\newtheorem` directives.

This is discussed in section 14.1 of the user guide of the `cleveref` package [highlighting added]:

[image]

Comment: One of the reasons why I always recommend loading packages first and then do settings.